# Grails createCriteria: finding objects via a field that is a null domain class instance

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm seeing some unexpected behavior in Grails' createCriteria.  I have a domain class that looks like this:

```
MyDomainClass {
    AnotherDomainClass anotherDomainClass
    static constraints = {
        anotherDomainClass(nullable:true)
    }
}
```

I want to find all instances of MyDomainClass where anotherDomainClass is null.  So I do this:

```
return MyDomainClass.createCriteria().list {
    eq('anotherDomainClass', null)
}
```

However, I get nothing back.

What am I doing wrong?  I can see there are database entries where the ANOTHERDOMAINCLASS_ID column is indeed null (or blank, I can't tell).

I'd be fine creating a query that references the ANOTHERDOMAINCLASS_ID column directly, but I haven't found a way yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of using eq you can use the isNull

```
def results = MyDomainClass.withCriteria {
    isNull('anotherDomainClass')
}
```

Here's a good reference [HibernateCriteriaBuilder Javadoc](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.html) too.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  Accepting this one over the other because it was first and provided sample code and a link to the javadocs.

Comment: Thanks. Here's another good reference (http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)

Comment: You could also use a dynamic finder if you don't have to check other conditions in the criteria, so you can just do def results = MyDomainClass.findAllByAnotherDomainClassIsNull() :-)

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you try `isNull` instead of `eq`?

EDIT: Could actually be `isEmpty` instead of `isNull`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a real answer, but my workaround for the time being is to retrieve *all* the objects from the database and filter in the app tier, like this:

```
MyDomainClass.list({it.anotherDomainClass == null})
```